# LINQ OrderBy - Custom

Tags: c#, linq

I have some data like

```
ID    Sequence  customIndex
1     1         0
2     2         0
3     3         2
4     4         1
5     5         0
```

I need to use sequence in order by when customIndex is zero other wise use customIndex.

So result should be ID in order of 1,2,4,3,5.

I need LINQ implementation using Lambda. I tried some solution but could not implement.

Posting duplicate and deleting previous one, because of wrong formatting the meaning of question got changed and I received bunch of negative votes.

Added code at dotnet fiddle:

https://stable.dotnetfiddle.net/fChl40

Comment: ID? result should be 12435 not 12345.

Comment: why negative vote and close request

Comment: I do not downvoted your question... I missed that ID is in order you rpovided (4 then 3).

Comment: Why `ID=5` is on the last position, if its customIndex is equal to 0 (zero)?

Comment: Np, so issue is use the sequence for ordering but use customIndex if it is not zero

Comment: The description of the sorting you need is incorrect: based on your very first sentence ("order by sequence when customIndex is zero other wise use customIndex"), the result should be ordered by Sequence 1, Sequence 2, CustomIndex 1, CustomIndex 2, Sequence 5; as you can see there are duplicate keys... Is it (the first sentence) the original request or is it your deduction based on the sample result (1,2,4,3,5) ? If the first case, then the result would be unpredictable or at least 1,4,2,3,5.

Comment: I understand its bit complex. basically use the sequence for sorting, but where ever items found with non-zero customIndex (consider a group of all non-zero items together in a sequence), here id 3,4 is first (and only, in this case) non-zero customIndex group, so re-sort those items based on customIndex.

Comment: So, customindex for id=5 must be changed to 3 ;)

Comment: Brilliant!!!!!!!!!!!!  PetSerAI's answer what I was expecting. Unfortuantely, its a comment, I cannot mark it as correct answer. Downvoter now relate my question with this answer

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The answer is based on assumption, that `CustomIndex` is greater or equals to zero:

```
var result = 
    data.OrderBy(x => x.CustomIndex==0 ? x.Sequence :
            data.Where(y => y.CustomIndex==0 && y.Sequence < x.Sequence)
                .Max(y => (int?)y.Sequence))
        .ThenBy(x => x.CustomIndex);
```

Answer (score 3):

This is working for provided test data:

```
    l.OrderBy(a => a.customIndex != 0 ? 
        list.Where(b => b.Sequence < a.Sequence && b.customIndex == 0)
            .OrderByDescending(c => c.Sequence)
            .FirstOrDefault()
            .Sequence : a.Sequence)
     .ThenBy(c=>c.customIndex )
     .ToList();
```

The idea is to order non zero values by first preceding zero valued rows, and then by non zero values itself.

Comment: nope...I tried this before...this will result in 4.3.1.2.5

Comment: that's perfect, but PetSerAI answered it first. I will wait for him to promote his comments as answer

Comment: `FirstOrDefault()` will return `null` if enumeration empty, and subsequent `.Sequence` will result `NullReferenceException`.

Answer (score 0):

This is something I wanted:

```
    public static void Main()
{
    List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
    data.Add(new Data{ Id=1, Sequence=1, CustomIndex=0});
    data.Add(new Data{ Id=5, Sequence=5, CustomIndex=0});
    data.Add(new Data{ Id=6, Sequence=6, CustomIndex=2});
    data.Add(new Data{ Id=2, Sequence=2, CustomIndex=0});
    data.Add(new Data{ Id=3, Sequence=3, CustomIndex=2});
    data.Add(new Data{ Id=4, Sequence=4, CustomIndex=1});

    data.Add(new Data{ Id=7, Sequence=7, CustomIndex=1});

    int o = 0;
    var result = data
        .OrderBy(x=>x.Sequence).ToList()
        .OrderBy((x)=> myCustomSort(x, ref o) )
            ;       
    result.ToList().ForEach(x=> Console.WriteLine(x.Id));
}

public static float myCustomSort(Data x, ref int o){

    if(x.CustomIndex==0){
        o = x.Sequence;
        return x.Sequence ;
    }
    else 
        return float.Parse(o + "."+ x.CustomIndex);
}
```

Sample code: https://stable.dotnetfiddle.net/fChl40
I will refine it further

Answer (score 0):

It ain't pretty, but it exemplifies what you were asking for, I think:

```
using System;
using System.Collections.Generic;
using System.Linq;

public class Program
{
    public static void Main()
    {
        List<Data> data = new List<Data>();
        data.Add(new Data { Id = 1, Sequence = 1, CustomIndex = 0 });
        data.Add(new Data { Id = 2, Sequence = 2, CustomIndex = 0 });
        data.Add(new Data { Id = 3, Sequence = 3, CustomIndex = 2 });
        data.Add(new Data { Id = 4, Sequence = 4, CustomIndex = 1 });
        data.Add(new Data { Id = 5, Sequence = 5, CustomIndex = 0 });

        //List of items where the sequence is what counts
        var itemsToPlaceBySequence = data.Where(x => x.CustomIndex == 0).OrderBy(x => x.Sequence).ToList();
        //List of items where the custom index counts
        var itemsToPlaceByCustomIndex = data.Where(x => x.CustomIndex != 0).OrderBy(x => x.CustomIndex).ToList();

        //Array to hold items
        var dataSlots = new Data[data.Count];

        //Place items by sequence
        foreach(var dataBySequence in itemsToPlaceBySequence) {
            dataSlots[dataBySequence.Sequence - 1] = dataBySequence ;
        }

        //Find empty data slots and place remaining items in CustomIndex order 
        foreach (var dataByCustom in itemsToPlaceByCustomIndex) {
            var index = dataSlots.ToList().IndexOf(null);
            dataSlots[index] = dataByCustom ;
        }

        var result = dataSlots.ToList();

        result.ForEach(x => Console.WriteLine(x.Id));
        var discard = Console.ReadKey();
    }

    public class Data
    {
        public int Id { get; set; }
        public int Sequence { get; set; }
        public int CustomIndex { get; set; }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

Based on your question and reply to my comment, I understand you need to clusterize the items' collection, then consider Sequence and CustomIndex on all items of each cluster.
Once clustered (split into blocks depending on a specific criterion) you can merge them back into a unique collection, but while doing that you can manipulate each cluster independently the way you need.

```
public static class extCluster
{
    public static IEnumerable<KeyValuePair<bool, T[]>> Clusterize<T>(this IEnumerable<T> self, Func<T, bool> clusterizer)
    {
        // Prepare temporary data
        var bLastCluster = false;
        var cluster = new List<T>();

        // loop all items
        foreach (var item in self)
        {
            // Compute cluster kind
            var bItemCluster = clusterizer(item);
            // If last cluster kind is different from current
            if (bItemCluster != bLastCluster)
            {
                // If previous cluster was not empty, return its items
                if (cluster.Count > 0)
                    yield return new KeyValuePair<bool, T[]>(bLastCluster, cluster.ToArray());

                // Store new cluster kind and reset items
                bLastCluster = bItemCluster;
                cluster.Clear();
            }

            // Add current item to cluster
            cluster.Add(item);
        }

        // If previous cluster was not empty, return its items
        if (cluster.Count > 0)
            yield return new KeyValuePair<bool, T[]>(bLastCluster, cluster.ToArray());
    }
}
// sample
static class Program
{
    public class Item
    {
        public Item(int id, int sequence, int _customIndex)
        {
            ID = id; Sequence = sequence; customIndex = _customIndex;
        }
        public int ID, Sequence, customIndex;
    }
    [STAThread]
    static void Main(string[] args)
    {
        var aItems = new[]
        {
            new Item(1, 1, 0),
            new Item(2, 2, 0),
            new Item(3, 3, 2),
            new Item(4, 4, 1),
            new Item(5, 5, 0)
        };

        // Split items into clusters
        var aClusters = aItems.Clusterize(item => item.customIndex != 0);
        // Explode clusters and sort their items
        var result = aClusters
            .SelectMany(cluster => cluster.Key
            ? cluster.Value.OrderBy(item => item.customIndex)
            : cluster.Value.OrderBy(item => item.Sequence));
    }
}
```

Answer (score -1):

The ordering you want to do (order partly on CustomIndex and partly on Sequence) doesn't work like that. But this should be close to what you want. Order first by CustomIndex, and then by Sequence.

```
var result = data.OrderBy(x => x.CustomIndex).ThenBy(x => x.Sequence);
```